# HTML Form to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Yes I know this has been asked a thousand times but I've searched and searched and none of the given answers seem to produce the right outcome.

Basically the output I want is below.

```
{
    "ResourceKey":"427693d6-16af-43a5-b6ff-89408cf460eb",
    "ResourceCategory":"HierarchyLevelResource",
    "Translations": [
        {
            "Translation": "English Hierarchy",
            "CultureCode": "en-GB"
        },
        {
            "Transation": "French Hierarchy",
            "CultureCode": "fr-FR"
        }
    ]
}
```

But all the answers seem to output the following instead.

```
{
   "ResourceKey": "427693d6-16af-43a5-b6ff-89408cf460eb",
   "ResourceCategory": "HierarchyLevelResource",
   "Translations[0].Translation": "English Hierarchy",
   "Translations[0].CultureCode": "en-GB",
   "Translations[1].Translation": "French Hierarchy",
   "Translations[1].CultureCode": "fr-FR"
}
```

C# MVC translates the first one perfectly as to me this is properly structured JSON were the second example it doesn't transform the 'Translations' elements.

Does anyone know of any libraries which translate the Form data correctly? I have been using the following which works perfectly for everything else apart from arrays.

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
var o = {};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function () {
    if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
        if (!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
});
return o;
};
```

EDIT: For further information my model is...

```
public class CustomLocalisationModel
{
    public string ResourceKey { get; set; }
    public string ResourceCategory { get; set; }
    public List<CustomLocalisationDataModel> Translations { get; set; }
}

public class CustomLocalisationDataModel
{
    public string CultureCode { get; set; }
    public string Translation { get; set; }
}
```

And it is put into the form in the following Razor Syntax...

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Localisation", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "translationsForm", novalidate = "novalidate", @class = "form-horizontal group-border-dashed", style = "border-radius:0px;"}))
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ResourceKey)
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ResourceCategory)

  for (var translationIndex = 0; translationIndex < Model.Translations.Count(); translationIndex++)
  {
       <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">@Model.Translations[translationIndex].LocalisedLanguageName</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Translations[translationIndex].Translation, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = PageLocaliser["PleaseEnterTranslation"].Value })
               @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Translations[translationIndex].CultureCode)
            </div>
        </div>
   }
   <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row xs-pt-15">
             <div class="col-xs-6">&nbsp;</div>
             <div class="col-xs-6">
                  <p class="text-right">
                     <button id="btnSaveLocalisations" type="submit" class="btn btn-space btn-primary" onclick="return SaveLocalisations();">@CommonLocaliser["SubmitLabel"]</button>
                     <button id="btnCancel" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit" class="btn btn-space btn-default" onclick="return false;">@CommonLocaliser["CancelLabel"]</button>
                  </p>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
}
```

EDIT 2:

Added Javascript Method used.

```
 function SaveLocalisations() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify($('#translationsForm').serializeObject()));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("Index", "Localisation", new {area = string.Empty})",
        data: JSON.stringify($('#translationsForm').serializeObject()),
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 7000,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(msg) {
            $.gritter.add({
                position: "top-right",
                title: "@CommonLocaliser["Success"]",
                text: "@PageLocaliser["UpdateSuccessMessage"].Value",
                class_name: 'clean img-rounded',
                time: 5000
            });

            $('#localisationPartial').modal('hide');
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            $.gritter.add({
                position: "top-right",
                title: "@CommonLocaliser["Failed"]",
                text: "@PageLocaliser["UpdateFailedMessage"].Value",
                class_name: 'clean img-rounded',
                time: 5000
            });
        }       
    });
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Is there some particular reason you want the 1st option (the 2nd is the default and will bind to your model - the 1st requires you to send the data as stringified and set the `contentType: 'application/json'` option

Comment: The first option works when testing via postman, the second doesn't. When testing the second one only performs the projection with the 'ResourceKey' and 'ResourceCategory' objects but not the 'Translations'. The first one however all works perfectly.

Comment: The 2nd does work! (you must be trying to override the default `contentType` option. The 2nd is created using (say) `$('form').serialize()` and will bind correctly using the default `contentType` (i.e. `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`)

Comment: You have not shown what `SaveLocalisations()` is - but all you need is (using jQuery)  - `$.post(yourUrl, $('#translationsForm').serialize(), function(response) { ... });`

Comment: Think I get what you're saying now. Rather than explicitly set the Ajax post to JSON actually send it through as a form post rather than a JSON message. I'll test now :D

Comment: I've added the SaveLocalisations method now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181833/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user2761804).

Comment: If you just need to pass the `Form data` to controller, there is no need to convert `FormData` to `Json`, what is the defination for `Index` action in `Localisation`. For passing model from `form-data`, you need to change Controller action like `(CustomLocalisationModel model)` or `[FromForm](CustomLocalisationModel model)`. You should not use the `[FromBody]`. Try `[FromForm]` with 2nd from postman.